# c++ how to find Duplicate by using for loops

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int* randnum(int* arr, int n) {
    int *ar = new int[n / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        ar[i] = rand() % n + 1;
    }

    return ar;
}

bool duplication(int* ar, int size) {

    if (size <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= size; j++) {

            if (ar[i] == ar[j]) {
                return true;
            }

            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    int n;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter a number : ";
        cin >> n;

        int size = n / 2;

        if (n <= 2) {
            cout << "Wrong number!!!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Size of random array : " << size << endl;

        int* arr = new int[size];

        cout << endl;
        cout << "[ Array ]" << endl;

        arr = randnum(arr, n);

        cout << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << arr[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;

        cout << endl;

        if (duplication(arr,size) == true)
            cout << "Duplicates found." << endl;

        if (duplication(arr, size) == false)
            cout << "Duplication not found." << endl;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------";
        cout << endl;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

i want to find duplicates in array.
but when the array is like [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8], it says "Duplication not found."
i think the for loops are wrong, but i don't know what is worng...

-> code explanation

int* randum : make random elements for array
bool duplication : if two or more elements are same, return true / if there's no duplicate return false

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= size; j++) {

            if (ar[i] == ar[j]) {
                return true;
            }

            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

This compares the first element with the second element, and if they are equal it returns `true`, otherwise it returns `false`. But you don't want that. What you want is to loop through the whole array and only return `false` if it never found a match.

Remove the `else return false;` in the loop and instead put a `return false;` at the end of the function (after the loops).

---

On a side note, you can find those duplicates more efficiently by sorting the array:

```
bool duplication(int* ar, int size) {
    return (std::adjacent_find(ar, ar + size) != ar + size);
}
```

Comment: omg! thank you so much:) i spent a lot of time for that TT thank you so much

Comment: Second problem (which the first masked): the outer loop runs off the end of the array. `i <=size` should be `i < size`.

Comment: @PeteBecker you're right, I changed the suggestion to use `std::adjacent_find` instead.